# Power Automate Expression for Multiply

Tags: azure-logic-apps, power-automate

**Issue :** Unable to multiply in Power Automate.

**Error Message :**

```
Unable to process template language expressions in action 'Sales_with_Delta' inputs at line '0' and column '0': 'The template language function 'int' was invoked with a parameter that is not valid. The value cannot be converted to the target type.'.
```

Expression used for multiplication :

```
mul(int(outputs('Compose')),float(variables('delta')))
```

**Flow Configuration**

[image]

**Question:**

- Can you please help with mul expression ?
- I want to multiply '`Sales`' with '`delta`' inside '`Sales with Delta`' variable

***Please note***

- I cannot change the variables declared as '`Compose`' or '`Object`'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be specific when you're referring to a property in an object, try this ...

```
mul(int(outputs('Compose')['Sales']),float(variables('delta')))
```

Worked for me ...

[image: Result]

... you may just need to work through the .00001 decimal part of the result that you may not want there.